# tagging photos in facebook-connect within iphone app

Tags: iphone, connection, facebook

Im adding a **fbConnect** feature in my iphone app. Was wondering if there is a way to **tag** photos (names, i.e. John Smith) in the fbConnect api?

Answer (score 1):

Photos.addTag is a facebook api which can be used to do this.